# Subtract Dictionary Values in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, dictionary

I have been trying to subtract a dictionary value from another in Google Earth Engine but it returns Nan

```
var dict = ee.Dictionary({
  B1: 182,
  B2: 219,
  B3: 443
});

print(dict.get('B1'));
print(dict.get('B2'));
print(dict.get('B2') - dict.get('B1'));
```

I don't know why it returns Nan instead of 37
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fails because the numbers are server-side objects, and you're trying to apply a client-side `-` operation on them. Read up on server- vs client-side [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/client_server). To do subtraction with server-side numbers, you do this:

```
a.subtract(b)
```

A second issue is that `ee.Dictionary.get()` returns an `ee.Element`. You have to cast it to an `ee.Number` before you use it:

```
ee.Number(dict.get('B2')).subtract(ee.Number(dict.get('B1')))
```

Alternatively, you can use `ee.Dictionary.getNumber()`, to directly get an `ee.Number`:

```
dict.getNumber('B2').subtract(dict.getNumber('B1'))
```

When you have more complex expression, it's often more readable to use `ee.Number.expression()`:

```
ee.Number.expression('B2 - B1', dict))
```

Finally, there are times where you actually don't need to use a server-side `ee.Dictionary`. Just go ahead and use a plain object, if that's the case:

```
var plainObject = {
  B1: 182,
  B2: 219,
  B3: 443
}
print(plainObject.B2 - plainObject.B1)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/903281ef4bfe0ac52f645f9747f44b56

Comment: How  to convert ee.Dictionary to plain object?

Comment: With `getInfo()` or `evaluate()`: https://code.earthengine.google.com/a8332104f78fc9dd7dc67b295af212b9